# Docker Compose file with Golang Template vars

Tags: go, docker-compose

I want to use something:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        environment:
           - TEMP123='{{ range $key, $value := . }}{{ $key }}{{end}}'
```

And I get result:

```
failed to create service nginx_nginx: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = expanding env failed: expanding env "TEMP123='{{ range ,  := . }}{{  }}{{end}}'": template: expansion:1: unexpected "," in range
```

May be I need to shield symbol '$' ?